# Pub-Sub issue when displaying latest created user and role in Meteorjs

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am using below meteor method to create a new user:

```
Meteor.methods({
"users.add": function(newUser) {
let cResult = Accounts.createUser({
username: newUser.username,
email: newUser.email
password: newUser.password,
profile: {
first_name: newUser.first_name,
last_name: newUser.last_name,
clinic: newUser.clinic
}
});
for (var index in newUser.roles) {
Roles.addUsersToRoles(cResult, newUser.roles[index].label);
}
return true;
},
"users.addRole": function(userId, newRole) {
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, newRole);
return true;
}
});
```

And the below code to subscribe to the mongo collection:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
let usersSubscription = Meteor.subscribe("allUsers");
let rolesSubscriptioin = Meteor.subscribe("allRoles");
const eachReady = usersSubscription.ready() && 
                  rolesSubscriptioin.ready();
const loading = usersSubscription ? !eachReady : true; 
return {
loading,
users: Meteor.users.find().fetch(),
roles: Meteor.roles.find().fetch()
};
})(Users);
```

I am using react to render the information.  When I am creating a new user, I am able to get the newly created user except for the roles information.  Leading to "undefined of map" error in the react component.

The component name is [user](https://github.com/tejaser/clinic/blob/master/client/imports/Users.jsx) and the repository is at this [link](https://github.com/tejaser/clinic):

I being new to meteor any help is good.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple solutions like getDerviedStateFromProps lifecycle method and everything else, I made a simple check for the undefined state when doing render which solved the problem without going into any lifecycle method.  It might be incorrect so still open to suggestions.